# Cannot set wxDateTime day, month and year

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying a very simple code for "licence expiry check". However, the following bit is always taking me to the first condition, i.e., expired, although I set the month to June. I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is. I would really appreciate some help.

```
LicDMY.LicDate = wxDateTime::Today(); 
LicDMY.TDay = wxDateTime::Today();
LicDMY.LicDate.SetYear(2019);
LicDMY.LicDate.SetMonth(wxDateTime::Jun);
LicDMY.LicDate.SetDay(30);
if(LicDMY.LicDate.IsEarlierThan(LicDMY.TDay)||LicDMY.LicDate.IsEqualTo(LicDMY.TDay))
    message = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Expired! Renew License \n"));
else
    message = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Welcome! \n"));
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=44287

Comment: @GinoMempin I tried printing them out. LicDate shows: 31-12-69__00-59-59 and TDay shows: 31-01-19__07-00-00 (in the format: ```LicDMY.LicDate.Format(wxT("%d-%m-%y__%H-%M-%S"), wxDateTime::CET );```)

Comment: @GinoMempin I still don't know why LicDate show year as 69. Could you please point out where I didn't specify it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `wxDateTime::SetMonth(wxDateTime::Jun)` would make the object invalid when its current day is 31, as it happens on Jan 31, when this question was asked. You could exchange the order of `SetDay()` and `SetMonth()` calls to make this work or, preferably, just use `Set(30, wxDateTime::Jun, 2019)` to change the entire date part at once or even write `LicDate = wxDateTime(30, wxDateTime::Jun, 2019)` which might be more readable.

Finally, it looks like you are not using debug facilities of wxWidgets (i.e. compile your code with `NDEBUG` defined) as otherwise you would have been immediately notified about the problem because you would have got an assertion failure with the message saying that `assert "(0 < day) && (day <= GetNumberOfDays(month, year))" failed in Set(): Invalid date in wxDateTime::Set()`. It is strongly recommended that you do use them, this is very helpful during development and will catch a lot of errors in your use of wxWidgets API.

Comment: So the same code that I posted is working today (Feb 1), without any changes made. It seems like SetDate(30) is the problem? Because it was working early, it didn't work yesterday when I tried (Jan 31). I don't know why that's the case as I am specifying the month to be June.

Comment: Oh, of course, I see. I've changed the answer to actually explain what's going on.

Comment: Thank you! And I'll use ```NDEBUG``` henceforth!

Comment: Just to be clear: you should _not_ define `NDEBUG` to get assertion failures. If you don't use it already and so use wxWidgets 3.0 or later, I don't see any reasonable explanation for why you're not getting them (i.e. this might be because you had explicitly compiled the library without debug support, but you would have been probably aware of doing this if you did...)